# How to create navigation drawer with 2 array

Tags: java, android

I have two array like below

`DB_id = [1,3,5,6,9]`

`DB_name = [a,b,c,d,e]`

I set `DB_name` array for my navigation drawer list like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name);
```

but I don't know how can I set DB_id as pos or id

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos, final long id){
            drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    String PosTxt = Integer.toString((pos+1));
                    aString = "SELECT * FROM MainContent WHERE GroupID LIKE '"+PosTxt+"'";
                    myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:fill_comment()");
                }
            });
            drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it with a subclass of ArrayAdapter

define a container class for your information, and override toString() to return name

```
public static class Container {
   public int id;
   public String name;

   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }    
}
```

then define a subclass of `ArrayAdater`, and override getItemId to make it return the id

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Container> {
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, Container[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
        }

       @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
             return getItem(position).id;
        }
}
```

then create a `Container[] objs`, and initialize its content. Last step is to use the custom adapter

```
MyAdapter<Container> adapter new MyAdapter<Container>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objs);
```

in `onItemClick`, use `id` instead of `position`

Comment: Sorry.I don't understand Container's job.please explain more

Comment: the contain wraps your information in one simple class. This way you don't have to maintain two different arrays.